# Using nested for loops to assign function outputs to a nested dict

Tags: python, function, dictionary, for-loop

I have an arbitrary function `func` that I'm running 3 times on different sets of inputs which correspond to run1, run2 and run 3 to generate 3 different sets of outputs. I'd like to save the key,value pairs in a nested dict and ideally in a nested dict structure to maintain consistency.

See below.

```
func()

input1_1 = a
input1_2 = b
input1_3 = c

input2_1 = d
input2_2 = e
input2_3 = f

input3_1 = g
input3_2 = h
input3_3 = i

output1_1, output1_2, output1_3 = func(input1_1, input1_2, input1_3)
output2_1, output2_2, output2_3 = func(input2_1, input2_2, input2_3)
output3_1, output3_2, output3_3 = func(input3_1, input3_2, input3_3)

results = {"results": {}}
```

I'm trying to make my final output like the following:

```
{'results': {'run1': {'output1_1': {},
                      'output1_2': {},
                      'output1_3': {}},
            {'run2': {'output2_1': {},
                      'output2_2': {},
                      'output2_3': {}},
            {'run3': {'output3_1': {},
                      'output3_2': {},
                      'output3_3': {}}}}
```

Comment: This question does not appear to be about [tag:pandas] so I have removed the tag. Even if a potential solution may include the library, that does not mean that it needs to be included in the question tags. If this question is about some sort of DataFrame reformatting or general Pandas Object manipulation please update your question to include these elements and re-add the tag.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you lack a fundamental understanding of both dictionaries and loops in Python.

The "final output" you want is not possible. Start with the object below and populate it with the output of your functions in loops. Good luck!

```
    results = {
        "run1": {"output1_1": {},"output1_2": {},"output1_3": {}},
        "run2": {"output1_1": {},"output1_2": {},"output1_3": {}},
        "run3": {"output1_1": {},"output1_2": {},"output1_3": {}}}
```